# problems converting string to JSON

Tags: android, json

Im creating this JSONObject in javascript.

```
    var jsonBack = {id:userID,"dateToday":today, dateYesterday:yesterday,
                   wbsArrayToday:[{wbs:"13232323"}, {wbs:"13232324"}, {wbs:"13232325"}],
                   wbsArrayYesterday:[{wbs:"13232333"}, {wbs:"13232334"}, {wbs:"13232335"}]};
```

Then i call this in my android application.

```
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
    // Henter response data fra server vha. httpResponse
    HttpEntity entity1 = response.getEntity();
    if (entity1 != null) {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = entity1.getContent();
            // convert stream to string
            String result = Converter.convertStreamToString(is);

            //Remove []
            //if(result.startsWith("["))
            //  result = result.substring(1, result.length()-1);
            // Create JSON Object
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HttpNodeClientException("HttpNodeClientException/IllegalStateException - createResponse():" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HttpNodeClientException("HttpNodeClientException/IOException - createResponse():" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HttpNodeClientException("HttpNodeClientException/JSONException - createResponse():" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ConverterException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HttpNodeClientException("HttpNodeClientException/ConverterException - createResponse():" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

And i get an JSONException. Did i design the JSON wrong?

Heres the exception:

```
08-14 16:14:18.522: I/LoginActivity(418): HttpNodeClientException/JSONException - createResponse
():Value {"id":"11111111","dateToday":"14082012","dateYesterday":"13082012","wbsArrayToday":
[{"wbs":"13232323"},{"wbs":"13232324"},{"wbs":"13232325"}],"wbsArrayYesterday":
[{"wbs":"13232333"},{"wbs":"13232334"},{"wbs":"13232335"}]} of type java.lang.String cannot be 
converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: The JSON also gets validated at http://jsonlint.com/!!

Comment: In short, you need way more double quotes.

Comment: The JSON puked up in the `Exception` is fine. Do a `println` of the JSON String before it goes to `JSONObject`.

Comment: Take a look at my answer in [HTTP Get Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526437/android-illegalstateexception-in-httpget/11526693#11526693). It may help you to parse the json string from a Web Service.

Comment: Ali thanks.. Im already doing it the same way. It just wont accept the the string when parsing to JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [JSONTokener](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html) class instead. It parses a string and return a JSON object.

Comment: So you use JSONTokener, if the JSON is complex(Containing arrays)?

Comment: @user1581164 Not too sure about the kissing bit but glad I could help. :) The JSONTokener gives you more control over the parsing since it can iterate over all tokens in the JSON object _or_ the actual tokens that are in the string to be parsed. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

the only line you need to fix is this one:

```
jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
```

into this one:

```
jsonObj = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(result));
```

Comment: JSONArray locations = object.getJSONArray("wbsArrayToday"); This will give me a JSONArray. But as you see, my JSONArray have an id(which is called "wbs") and a value. How to get the value by pointing at the id and index? Cause locations.getString(1) gives both values...

Comment: in this case i would use for(int i = 0; i<locations.size(); i++){ JSONObject wbsAux = (JSONObject) locations.get(i);.....  this will give access to every json object in your array, and you can ask the value to each one of them. still, im kinda new with android as well, but have used this and checked that it works